# printing a single value of a list with enumerate function

Tags: python, list, if-statement, range, enumerate

I have the following statement:

**for i, char in enumerate(list(range(100))):**

now i just want to print the value, where char is equal to 50.

I have tried the following idea, but did not understand why it is incorrect:

```
for i, char in enumerate(list(range(100))):

  char == 50

  print(i)
```

The solution is that I have to put an "if" statement, i already understood the logic behind it but also want to ask, why my approach is not valid.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: So, what is the expected result... to be `50` or something else?

Comment: Your statement `char == 50` computes a `True` or `False` value, but then does not use it for anything.  If you want to use this as the basis of a condition, then you will need an `if` statement.

Comment: Some other comments: (a) the variable name `char` suggests that it contains a character but actually contains an integer; try to avoid misleading variable names because they can make the code harder to debug; (b) you can use `enumerate(range(100))` directly; you do not need to convert the object returned by `range` into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just have to use the `if` condition like so:

```
for i, char in enumerate(list(range(100))):
    if char == 50:   #<--- add if here
        print(i)     #<--- inside the if-condition
```

Also, I see there is no need to use `enumerate` or `list`.